# Reduce Lethargy Equation

Tags: asymptotics, logarithms

I need to prove that $$1-\frac{(A-1)^2}{2A}\ln \frac{A+1}{A-1}$$ approximately equals $\dfrac{2}{A+2/3}$.

I think that we can expand the $\ln$ to $2(1/A+1/(3A^3)+\dots)$ and so the first term multiplied by the polynomial and all reduces to $2/A$ since $1/A^2$ -> really quickly. Can anyone help me reduce this  equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! It really helps readability to format questions using MathJax (see FAQ). Regards

Answer (score 1):

It helps to take $x=1/A$. Then the function becomes
$$1-\frac{x(1/x-1)^2}{2}\ln \frac{1+x}{1-x}$$
The Taylor expansion at $x=0$ (best found with CAS) is 
$$2x-\frac43 x^2 + \frac23 x^3 + \dots $$
which agrees up to second order with 
$$\frac{2}{1/x+2/3} = 2x-\frac43 x^2 + \frac89 x^3 -\dots$$